# How to assign an array to spots in fl_chart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, graph, charts, fl-chart

I am new to Flutter and just started using [`fl_charts`](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) which really looks fantastic. However I am struggling to move beyond demo LineChartSample1.

The [sample code given here](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/line_chart/samples/line_chart_sample1.dart) assigns values to spots as follows:

```
  spots: [
    FlSpot(1, 1.4),
    FlSpot(2, 3.4),
    FlSpot(3, 2),
    FlSpot(4, 2.2),
    FlSpot(5, 1.8),
  ],
```

In real life this obviously will have to be dynamic. Hence I need to  assign values from an array of numbers like this:

```
myArray = [7578, 7547, 3578, 9875]
```

I can't figure out how to assign this array to spots assuming that first parameter to FlSpot is just a sequence like 0, 1, 2, 3 ... and second parameter coming from myArray.

I need something like `FlSpot(x++, myArray[x])` in a loop.

Comment: which type of chart are you using?

Comment: Line, Bar charts using https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Answer (score 5):

sorry for the late answer,
I will follow the fl-chart tag to answer earlier.
There is an operator called `map`, it converts your current data to a new different data model.
you can use like this:

```dart
final List<double> yValues = [
    1.3,
    1,
    1.8,
    1.5,
    2.2,
    1.8,
    3,
  ];

List<FlSpot> spots =  
      yValues.asMap().entries.map((e) {
         return FlSpot(e.key.toDouble(), e.value);
      }).toList(),

// now spots are [
//    FlSpot(0, 1.3),
//    FlSpot(1, 1),
//    FlSpot(2, 1.8),
//    FlSpot(3, 1.5),
//    FlSpot(4, 2.2),
//    FlSpot(5, 1.8),
//    FlSpot(6, 3),
//  ];
```

Comment: how can I plot the spots with 2 different arrays for the x and y axis respectively?

Answer (score 1):

First you can pass the data static to fl_chart means the point you want to show there like this:

spots: [
FlSpot(1, 1.4),
FlSpot(2, 3.4),
FlSpot(3, 2),
FlSpot(4, 2.2),
FlSpot(5, 1.8),
],

for adding the dynamic value from list you have to use the code

RxList analyticPlots = [].obs;

```
List.generate(widget.list.length, (i) {

  analyticPlots.add(
      FlSpot(i.toDouble(), 
      double.parse(widget.list[i].value.toString())));

});
```