# Flutter: fl_chart Pass Two Arrays To FlSpot()

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61987521/16806413) shows how to pass one array to a `List<FlSpot>`, however, I need to pass two different arrays of doubles. I cannot figure out how to get both arrays into a single `List<FlSpot>` for the x and y variables of the spots.

```
//this holds the date information in a list of doubles
List<int> datesSec = logRecord.updatesDateEpoch.asList();
List<double> dateTimeDouble = datesSec.map((d) => d.toDouble()).toList();

//this holds units information in a list of doubles
List<double> unitsList = logRecord.updatesUnits.toList();

//This is where I need to figure out how to pass both of them to a list of FlSpot
List<FlSpot> spots = dateTimeDouble.map((e) => FlSpot(e, e)).toList();
```

How do I pass both the `dateTimeDouble` list to the x variable and the `unitsList` to the y variable?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I was able to figure this out

```
List<FlSpot> newSpots = [for (int i = 0; i < dateTimeDouble.length; i++)
  FlSpot(dateTimeDouble[i], unitsList[i])];
```